Gradle "Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'." error on Intellij
I'm just trying out spring boot, and tried to import a spring boot project onto Intellij and simply run it. The build just keeps failing every time despite trying a bunch of different solutions. This is the error I'm getting:
./gradlew build --warning-mode=all

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'adhdplanner'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:3.2.5.
     Required by:
         project : > org.springframework.boot:org.springframework.boot.gradle.plugin:3.2.5
      > No matching variant of org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:3.2.5 was found. The consumer was configured to find a library for use during runtime, compatible with Java 8, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally, as well as attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '8.7' but:
          - Variant 'apiElements' declares a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component for use during compile-time, compatible with Java 17 and the consumer needed a component for use during runtime, compatible with Java 8
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.7')
          - Variant 'javadocElements' declares a component for use during runtime, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.7')
          - Variant 'mavenOptionalApiElements' declares a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component for use during compile-time, compatible with Java 17 and the consumer needed a component for use during runtime, compatible with Java 8
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.7')
          - Variant 'mavenOptionalRuntimeElements' declares a library for use during runtime, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component, compatible with Java 17 and the consumer needed a component, compatible with Java 8
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.7')
          - Variant 'runtimeElements' declares a library for use during runtime, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component, compatible with Java 17 and the consumer needed a component, compatible with Java 8
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.7')
          - Variant 'sourcesElements' declares a component for use during runtime, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.7')

* Try:
> Review the variant matching algorithm at https://docs.gradle.org/8.7/userguide/variant_attributes.html#sec:abm_algorithm.
> No matching variant errors are explained in more detail at https://docs.gradle.org/8.7/userguide/variant_model.html#sub:variant-no-match.
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

This is my build.gradle. The sourceCompatibility is grey, I added the "buildscript" section, changed the versions, etc:
buildscript{
    ext{
        springBootVersion = '3.2.5.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'idea'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.2.5'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.4'
}

group = 'org.example'
version = '1.0-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.6'

compileJava.options.fork = true
compileJava.options.forkOptions.executable = true

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

This is gradle-wrapper.properties:
#Tue Apr 23 12:49:14 EDT 2024
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.7-bin.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists

This is my Main():
package org.example;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello world!");
    }
}

I tried versions ll, 21, and 22, but I still get the same errors:
Project Structure
Settings
I'm not sure if I gave enough information, please let me know.

I had the same issue and resolved it. Here are the resolution steps:

Update the Java version to openjdk-19.0.1
Open IntelliJ Settings -> Build, Execution, Environment -> Build Tools -> Gradle -> Update Gradle JVM
Open IntelliJ File Menu -> Project Structure ->
a. Project Project Settings -> Project -> SDK :  Update the latest path
b. Platform Settings -> SDKs: Keep the latest JDK and remove the
older JDKs
Then Clean and Re-Build the project Or, Restart the IDE

Please recheck it once, you might have missed the step 3.b.

you save my day! my case is I import a new project into IDEA, and in my local machine my JAVA_HOME is java11, then the default SDK version for gradle VM be  set to 11, then i check and use your option#2: "Open IntelliJ Settings -> Build, Execution, Environment -> Build Tools -> Gradle -> Update Gradle JVM" to SDK default(java17), then every thing works!

Spring Boot 3.2.5 needs Java 17 (docs) and you are trying to run Gradle with Java 8.
I see you have Java 21 installed already. Make sure that is your project SDK (as you have in the screenshot, in File | Project Structure, docs), and also check it is being used by Gradle (Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Gradle) (docs).
EDIT: I see you've tried all that already. Perhaps your JAVA_HOME environment variable is overriding it.
You could either: (i) set your JAVA_HOME environment variable however you configure Java or your system's environment to point to your Java 21 installation (I like using jenv to manage such things), or you could (ii) override it in a gradle.properties file.
For the latter, add such a file to the root of your project and place the following in it:
org.gradle.java.home=path/to/my/jdk

(obviously replacing the path with the correct one(docs)).
